# Why All for One didnt keep a regeneration quirk for himself?

Tags: my-hero-academia

According to [Super Regeneration - Boku No Hero Academia Wikia](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Regeneration)

> This Quirk has the ability to regenerate any sort of injuries on the
>   user's body, such as missing limbs, at incredible speeds.
>
> All For One once stole and tried to use this Quirk to heal himself
>   from the heavy damage All Might caused to him, but because his body
>   had already cicatrized those injuries, the Quirk had no effect and was
>   considered useless.

So, because he couldnt heal the injuries he already cicatrized, he considered this quirk was useless. That doesnt seem to have any sense. Why he didnt keep the quirk to heal new injuries in new battles? That would seem to be a very useful quirk, even if fighting All Might again.

Answer (score 3):

When All for One first appears in the manga in chapter 59, he talks about, how he wished to have gotten the regeneration quirk sooner (it probably took a long time to get that quirk, since it is so rare), because his wounds had already healed at the time, when he finally got his hands on it. So for those injuries, which had been caused by All Might, the quirk was useless.

But it doesn't say anywhere in the manga, that he doesn't still have it. So, it is very likely, that he still has it and uses it for new injuries.

Comment: If that is the case, don't you think that he would regenerate in the last fight with All Might? He just got K.O with a punch from All Might!

Comment: @IdkWhy Regeneration still takes time and uses stamina depending on how badly someone is injured (e.g. Deku was given super regeneration from Recovery Girl, but it still took some time for his broken arms to be healed). Also, if All For One is unconscious (KO), he is not able to use any quirks (i.e. he can't use regeneration).

Comment: The quirk from Recovery Girl and From AFO is totally diferent, the quirk from recovery girl takes time, the Super Regeneration from AFO is incredible fast as wiki says, Nomu regenerated an entire arm in seconds! Recovery Girl has heal, not super regenaration

Comment: @IdkWhy My mistake, but he still can't use it, if he is unconscious (KO).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I see it like this is you cut off your arm just below the elbow and use fire to cicatrized the wound then the regeneration quirk would not right. But if you then cut your arm again after cicatrizing the stump at the shoulder would regen regrow the whole or to the stump